# How to preserve CVS tags during cvs2git conversion?

Tags: cvs2git

I'm converting a number of CVS repositories to GIT. That works mostly but when a CVS repository used tags, these are missing in the GIT repository (branches wortk, though).

Strangely enough the cvs2svn output shows a number of identified tags:

```
cvs2svn Statistics:
------------------
Total CVS Files:               199
Total CVS Revisions:          1223
Total CVS Branches:              0
Total CVS Tags:               9378 
Total Unique Tags:              67   <-----
Total Unique Branches:           0
CVS Repos Size in KB:         2787
Total SVN Commits:             785
First Revision Date:    Thu Mar  3 16:41:25 2011
Last Revision Date:     Fri Jul  3 08:11:25 2015
```

My template for the options can be seen here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11919176/

My command sequence:

```
cvs2git --options=options.file
mkdir $repo.git
cd $repo.git
git init --bare
git fast-import --export-marks=../git-marks.dat < ../git-blob.dat
git fast-import --import-marks=../git-marks.dat < ../git-dump.dat
```

cvs2svn version is 2.3.0

I've googled around for hours now, but still have no clue what's missing. 
Any help please?

Comment: Please post all relevant content here; don't link to external options file.

Comment: I can't, body size exceeds maximum allowed number of characters.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that it was a large template. I assumed it was a small file you'd written.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind. The conversion actually imported all tags, but I had to add an additional step to upload the tags to the server:

```
git push --tags -u origin
```